# IntelliJ: unable to import SBT project

Tags: intellij-idea, sbt

I've been using IntelliJ with SBT successfully for a while, but lately I've been unable to import SBT projects.

I'll do the following:

- Create new project > Empty project
- Specify a new to-be-created folder
- Add > Import module in the dialog, or New > Module from existing sources from the menu
- Select the folder containing the SBT project
- Select SBT
- Finish

The project does not show up anywhere in IntelliJ. The status line says "Unable to save settings". If I try to import the project once again I get "This project is already registered".

Here is a snippet from `idea.log` that looks like it could be relevant:

```
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Cannot get libraryTable component state
    at com.intellij.configurationStore.ComponentStoreImpl.save(ComponentStoreImpl.kt:166)
... 38 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.project.ScalaLibraryProperties.getState(ScalaLibraryProperties.scala:30)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.project.ScalaLibraryProperties.getState(ScalaLibraryProperties.scala:14)
    at com.intellij.openapi.roots.impl.libraries.LibraryImpl.writeExternal(LibraryImpl.java:368)
    at com.intellij.openapi.roots.impl.libraries.LibraryTableBase$LibraryModel.writeExternal(LibraryTableBase.java:363)
    at com.intellij.openapi.roots.impl.libraries.LibraryTableBase.getState(LibraryTableBase.java:63)
    at com.intellij.openapi.roots.impl.libraries.LibraryTableBase.getState(LibraryTableBase.java:45)
    at com.intellij.configurationStore.ComponentStoreImpl.commitComponent(ComponentStoreImpl.kt:227)
    at com.intellij.configurationStore.ComponentStoreImpl.save(ComponentStoreImpl.kt:159)
```

IntelliJ 2017.2.3, Scala plugin 2017.2.6.

Comment: is there a public repo to reproduce this?

Comment: Is there a reason you are importing an sbt project as a module into an empty project instead of  as a standalone project?

Comment: Since this sounds like a bug I've created an issue for you and will try to reproduce it later: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-12539

Comment: Thanks. Yes, reason is to use project as container for several modules.

Comment: This seems to be solved in recent versions.